# Parametrization of the hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^5$ given by $ x + y + z + w + at = b$

Tags: linear-algebra

Parametrization of the hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^5$ given by $ x + y + z + w + at = b$ where $a,b$ are real numbers.

I'm a bit confused on what a solution to this looks like (maybe I'm overthinking it). So we'll have dimension of four and all solutions would be in the form $ x = at + b$, but without being given any vectors and told to assume $a,b$ have real values is that it?

Comment: The vector orthogonal to the plane is $ \vec u=(1,1,1,1,a)^T$ and the equation can be written as $\vec u \cdot (x-b,y,z,w,t)^T=0$

Comment: What about $(x,y,z,w,t)=(f(s),-f(s),g(r)+m,-g(r),\frac ba-m)$. There are a lot of parameterizations.

Answer (score 0):

We can rewrite as
$$
\alpha \cdot (x,y,z, w, t) = b \\
\alpha = (1,1,1,1,a) \\
\lVert \alpha \rVert^2 = 4 + a^2 \ne 0 \\
n = \alpha / \lVert \alpha \rVert \\
d = b / \lVert \alpha \rVert
$$
where $n$ is a normal unit vector of the hyperplane and $d$ is the signed distance to the origin.